# AmCharts dataloader doesn't work with generate series plugin using stock chart

Tags: amcharts

I am loading JSON that works in AmCharts' plugin but I'm having trouble making it work with external JSON and the stock chart. I'm using the code from this example here: https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/automatically-generate-series-graphs-data-stock-chart/

I'm using this dataLoader config below:

```
"dataLoader": {
  "url": "data/MSFT.json", 
  "format": "json", 
  "showCurtain": true, 
  "showErrors": true, 
  "async": true
}
```

The plugin works as expected when my data is provided directly in the dataProvider as static JSON, but not using the dataLoader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin you linked to isn't designed to work with the dataloader, but you can make some minor adjustments to make it play nice with it by following what the [datePadding plugin](https://github.com/amcharts/tools/tree/master/datePadding) does by wrapping the main logic into a function that can be called later, then adding some code to check for the presence of the dataLoader before attaching the call to the dataLoader's complete callback:

```
AmCharts.addInitHandler(function(chart) {  
  function generateGraphsFromSeries(chart) { 
    //original logic here
  }
  //determine whether the dataloader is used or not
  /**
     * Stock or Serial chart?
     */
    if ( chart.type === "stock" ) {

        // check each data set if there's a Data Loader active
        var loader;
        for ( var i = 0; i < chart.dataSets.length; i++ ) {
            if ( chart.dataSets[ i ].dataLoader !== undefined && chart.dataSets[ i ].dataLoader.url !== undefined ) {
                loader = chart.dataSets[ i ].dataLoader;
            }
        }

        // is there at least one data loader?
        if ( loader === undefined ) {
            // nope - let's go with processing
            generateGraphsFromSeries( chart );
        } else {
            // yeah - let's use the last data loader's complete event
            if ( loader.complete ) {
                loader._complete = loader.complete;
            }
            loader.complete = function( chart ) {
                // call original complete
                if ( loader._complete )
                    loader._complete.call( this, chart );

                // now let's do our thing
                generateGraphsFromSeries( chart );
            }
        }

    } else if ( chart.stockChart === undefined && chart.id !== "scrollbarChart" ) {

        // check for Data Loader
        var loader = chart.dataLoader;
        if ( loader !== undefined && loader.url !== undefined ) {
            if ( loader.complete ) {
                loader._complete = loader.complete;
            }
            loader.complete = function( chart ) {
                // call original complete
                if ( loader._complete )
                    loader._complete.call( this, chart );

                // now let's do our thing
                generateGraphsFromSeries( chart );
            }
        } else {
            generateGraphsFromSeries( chart );
        }

    }
}, ["serial", "stock"]);
```

Here's an [updated demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/8ae34270413f90f88174e19a8bc6e5b2?editors=0010) that demonstrates this working with an external JSON file.

Also note that the stock chart expects the dataLoader to be inside a `dataSet` object in the dataSets array, unlike with serial charts:

```
AmCharts.makeChart("...", {
  type: stock,
  // ...
  dataSets: [{
    dataLoader: {
      // config
    },
    //rest of the config here.
  },
    // repeat for each dataSet
  ],
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Dear Tanks a alot about your Feedback it's Work for Me , Another issue it happend for Me , When i put two amstock in a html page I recive error AS : Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle or codepen that reproduces this.

Comment: Dear I try to have two js file same my project but in them not possible https://codepen.io/artamoeini/details/paydEN/  , I explain my content file and html content in comment of this codepen also

Comment: You have to define a width and height for the second chart div. You only have CSS for #chartdiv, so adding an additional rule for #chartdiv1 will fix it.